# update winform from other class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform containing controls that are updated when a new instance of my business logic class is instantiated.  And with the use of a timer, fields in my class (and their associative labels) are updated every few seconds.

This is all working fine, except for one control - a rich text box acting as a log of all the activity.

The problem is this: though I want all the other controls to be refreshed when a new class is instantiated, I don't want the log to be refreshed.  I want it to store all the previous activity (from the current session; it doesn't need to persist between application lifetimes.)

I can't store the log data in a class instance obviously, so what method should I be using? Is it worth creating a Singleton for this?

And how should I go about adding an entry to the log?

Comment: i didnt down vote you, but the question isnt clear and you havent posted any code so people aren't likely to be able to help :)

Comment: It is unclear why you can't store log data in a class instance - anything can be stored in a class instance.  If this is string data, why not just store it in your form, or in objects contained by your form?

Comment: +1 to balance out the downvote, but as flesh recommended, please provide more information.

Comment: I totally deserve the downvotes - I wrote this in haste.  However, Andy West caught my drift and offered the suggestion of storing the data in the form.  I was wondering if that was a common/accepted process.  Thanks guys!  Andy - feel free (if the SO rules allow it) to upgrade your post as a real answer and you'll have your answer accepted.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The only reason I made it a comment is because I wasn't sure I could answer without more info. I'm glad it helped.  This is ok for basic logging, but if it's very involved you may want to take Judah's advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Posted as an answer from my original comment, as requested by fieldingmellish*:

If this is string data, you could just store it in your form, or in objects contained by your form.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to logging, don't reinvent the wheel. There are a few free, solid logging tools out there:

[NLog](http://nlog-project.org/documentation.html)

[log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)

If I recall right, NLog has built-in support for writing its log to a text box.